# Quick start with using opengl on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to make a game in opengl. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make square in OpenGL in java :[
I read JayWay Tutorials, but these tutorials are...
strange....
Why? These tutorials are complex and I don't understand as I make square xD
Can you help me? Can you give me a simple project/tutorial I could learn this?

Comment: "They are ... strange", so I guess they give an extensive introduction to OpenGL and its underlying principles, instead of a simple "copy this exact code into your program to draw a square"-answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Android developer network gives a (very) high level overview of how OpenGL and Android work together [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).  They also provide a link to a few sample projects that involve drawing simple shapes.  Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/index.html) for some examples that may help you.  In the future, it would be better if you posted what exactly you're struggling with instead of a general "I don't get it!"

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629775/tutorials-and-libraries-for-opengl-es-games-on-android) question should be very helpful for you.