# graphical shape 3D in android

Tags: android, graphics

I want to create a graphical human shape in android. I want to result to look something like this:
[image: enter image description]

Well, maybe a little bit different, but I haven't found a better picture.Anyway, the question:

Is there possible to create something like?Is there any `source code` or some `classes` to help you design this?
I don't want to create this by myself, starting from zero.I want to reuse code.
And also tutorials are more than welcome.

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this question (it contains some useful resources (tutorials) on graphics for android:

[Tutorials and libraries for OpenGL-ES games on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629775/tutorials-and-libraries-for-opengl-es-games-on-android)

Probably also that page could help you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Comment: so, I must use OpenGl to obtain that?

Comment: my guess is yes, since openGL is used for 3d graphics, it seems to be a nice idea :)