# 3D Scene Creation & SDK

Tags: android, 3d, scene

I am looking to create a 3D scene for Android devices.

I do not know where to begin, so help would be appreciated.

I, basically, need to create the 3d scene (what to use?) allow objects to be added or removed from the scene, and have an SDK to load and display the scene on an Android device.

I know all this would be ideal in a single resource, but I know I will have to adapt function calls to JNI/Android OpenGL.

Any help for how to get started or where to begin research would be appreciated.

PS. I will use a viewport to look into the scene from different perspectives.

Comment: I think I was a little too vague on what exactly I wanted - a wrapper LIB specifically designed to bring in a full scene and maintain it.  Something more like UNITY3D Does, but I can't find anything that does this right now for android.  I think it was more a pipe dream, so I'm going to have to take the route of rendering each and every object individually and handling them all on a lower level than something as simple as bringing in a scene that would place objects in a 3d world and let me manipulate them when needed.  BTW, Min3D looks like its not as updated as maybe LIBGDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something more advanced but processing.org is a great place to start if you just want to use Java.

There is a Processing.org IDE for Android and you can use a plugin for eclipse.

There are a lot of great 3D modelling libraries that are easy and fun to use but also really good.

Here are a few links that may help if you think it's worth looking at.

[One of many cool videos showing what you can do with processing.org](http://vimeo.com/20068501)

[A less cool but interesting demo](http://vimeo.com/7583551)

[Some libraries](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/)

[The processing Android Wiki](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android)

Comment: Ruairi, sorry for the delay is accepting you answer, but I've learned more about what i wanted to do and finally found a library solution.  While loading a scene is not difficult (once you understand), I chose the library path to let me work on my product and not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: what is the name of the library??

Answer (score 0):

Follow the links...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html

[Tutorials and libraries for OpenGL-ES games on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629775/tutorials-and-libraries-for-opengl-es-games-on-android)

http://www.enfis.it/archives/14