# Android game development.

Tags: android, opengl-es, opencl

Is it possible to develop android games and application if we have good knowledge in C,OpenCL,OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure You can please check the below links

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html

[Tutorials and libraries for OpenGL-ES games on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629775/tutorials-and-libraries-for-opengl-es-games-on-android)

http://obviam.net/index.php/opengl-es-with-android-switching-from-canvas-to-opengl/

Answer (score 2):

of course! you just need to learn some java a bit and some android [fundamental](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). Ed Burnette covers some opengl stuff in his "[Hello, Android"](http://pragprog.com/book/eband/hello-android) book. Read that chapter to see how your knowledge can correlate to android development.

Answer (score 2):

Sure,you can.Here is a good open souce on game engine ,and it has a lot on opengl.
Check this:[AndEngine.](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine)
And this forum: [AndEngine forum](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/eclipse-andengine-and-helloworld-t380.html)
Enjoy.