# Looking for tutorials on drawing shapes with OpenGL ES 1.0 in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, shapes

Despite my best efforts, I'm having trouble locating tutorials or general information that aid in learning to utilize OpenGL ES 1.0 to draw shapes such as spheres, cones, etc. I've followed the Android OpenGL ES tutorial for drawing a triangle and have played with that code quite extensively. I'd just like to know how I can move on to more complicated shapes and use of OpenGL ES.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1629775/529138 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to look at these one it was very helpful for me when learning openGl with android

1. [Drawing  Different object using open gl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMwnTSk6hJo)  with some sources that may help you
2. [see also this link](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of my own samples:

- [ObjViewer](https://github.com/ldo/ObjViewer_Android) for interactive viewing of .obj files
- [3D Compass](https://github.com/ldo/3D-Compass), which demonstrates off-screen compositing of a 3D model with camera images.